# Google serves its homepage to urllib2 when a local search is made

Tags: python, urllib2, google-search, httplib, google-local-search

When a local search is done on Google, then the user clicks on the 'More ...' link below the map, the user is then brought to a page such as [this](https://www.google.com/ncr#q=chiropractors%2BNew+York,+NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl).

If the URL:

```
https://www.google.com/ncr#q=chiropractors%2BNew+York,+NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl
```

is copied out and pasted back into a browser, one arrives, as expected, at the same page. Likewise when a browser is opened with **WebDriver**, directly accessing the URL brings WebDriver to the same page.

When an attempt is made, however, to request the same page with **urllib2**, Google serves it its home page (google.com), and it means, among other things, that **lxml**'s extraction capabilities cannot be used.

While **urllib2** is not the culprit here (perhaps Google does the same with all headless requests), is there any way of getting Google to serve the desired page? A quick tests with the `requests` library is indicating the same issue.

Comment: A downvote without an explanation helps nobody. I welcome constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the big hint here is in the URL:

`https://www.google.com/ncr#q=chiropractors%2BNew+York,+NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl`

Do you notice how there is that hash character (`#`) in there? Everything following the hash component is never actually sent to the server, so the server can't process it. This indicates (in this case) that the page you are seeing in WebDriver and in your browser is a result of client side scripting.

When you load up the page, your browser sends a request for `https://www.google.com/ncr` and google returns the home page. The homepage contains javascript that analyses the component after the hash and uses it to generate the page that you *expect* to see. The browser and Webdriver can do this because they process the javascript. If you disable javascript in your browser and go to that link, you'll see that the page isn't generated either.

**urllib2** however, does not process javascript. All it sees is the HTML that the website initially sent along with the javascript, but it can't process the javascript that actually generates the page you are expecting.

Google *is serving the page you're asking for*, but your problem is that urllib2 is not equipped to render it. To fix this, you'll have to use a scraping framework that supports Javascript. Optionally in this particular case, you could simply use the non-javascript version of Google for your scraping.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Yes I had glanced at the source, and, seeing a ton of Javascript and very little text, assumed it was the homepage. What is this non-javascript version of Google you are referring to?

Comment: @Pyderman No problem! Google renders the majority of the interface client-side nowadays because it provides a better experience, but they still support the old interface. If you disable Javascript in your browser you'll be navigating using the non-JS interface, and those links will work as expected with `urllib2`. For example, here is a JS-disabled link similar to your original query: https://www.google.com/search?q=chiropractors+New+York%2C+NY&btnG=Search

Comment: @Pyderman Please note, though, that the exact page that you linked is a Google Maps link. Google maps requires JS so you won't be able to get a non-JS version of that exactly. The non-JS version of Google also differs in a few other, subtle ways. You might want to look into using a crawler that supports javascript if that will cause you problems :)